# Does the number of streaming sources depends on the number of cores your chip have?

Tags: hardware, esp32

To give a bit more context to my question, I have an ESP32 microcontroller and want to stream audio and video data to a web server, and also receive live audio and video from the web server's clients (4 stream sources). Does than mean I need 4 cores to "asynchronously" process these data? If so, ESP32 only have 2 cores, are there any techniques to handle the data with as little interrupt on the core as possible?

Comment: Short answer: no you could handle a dozen streaming sources with one core if the processor is fast enough to handle them all. I don't know about the esp32 specifically.

Answer (score 0):

ESP32 runs a version of FreeRTOS. You can create multiple tasks or threads that run simultaneously.
Check out this link for a nice getting started tutorial: [ESP32 FreeRTOS Tutorial](https://www.digikey.in/en/maker/projects/introduction-to-rtos-solution-to-part-2-freertos/b3f84c9c9455439ca2dcb8ccfce9dec5)